# removing characters from a list of strings

Tags: python, list

I have a character matrix that looks something like this:

```
["AAAAAAAA",
 "AAAXAAAA",
 "AAAAAAAA"]
```

I have numeric x/y coordinates for the location of the x and I want to get a string that contains all the letters in that matrix except for the x, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What do the coordinates look like:  `[1, 3]`?  Also, In your example code, what output do you expect?  It seems like you could just do `'A' * (number_of_elements_in(matrix) - number_of_coordinates_to_remove)`.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempt at this, even if it's not the best way.

Comment: What's your desired output? One string, or a list of three strings?

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient, but a starting point:

```
>>> matrix = [
...     "AAAAAAAA",
...     "AAAXAAAA",
...     "AAAAAAAA"]
>>> x, y = 4, 2

>>> linear = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matrix))
>>> del linear[x - 1 + (y - 1) * 8]
>>> ''.join(linear)
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a solution using Python's awesome list comprehension:

```
coordinates = (1,3) # (line, column)
matrix = ["AAAAAAAA",
    "AAAXAAAA",
    "AAAAAAAA"]

matrix = [list(line) for line in matrix] # convert the strings to create a "real" matrix" 
del matrix[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]] # delete the specified element

"".join([item for line in matrix for item in line]) # flatten out the matrix and creating a string
```